# Bubble sort not compiling c

Tags: c

I'm using a source.c , i use the same console as c++, this hasn't given me an issue before. The issue its giving me is pointing to the bubbleSort function, but i was following a video step by step to get mine to work i suscpect i have a pointer wrong or a variable.
I am fairly new to C programming and tend to make mistakes i cannot find. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct SalesRep  //creating sturcture
{
    char name[20];
    int Sales;
};

void bubbleSort(SalesRep *a,int n);


int main()
{
    int *a;  //dynamic array pointer
    int i,n;

    struct SalesRep *s;



printf("How many sales to be entered for dynamic array?");   //getting dynamic array info
scanf_s("%d",&n);

a=(int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));

s=(SalesRep*)calloc(n,sizeof(SalesRep));

printf("Enter Sales rep name and sales:");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("Enter name:\n");
    scanf("%s",s[i].name);
    printf("enter sales:\n");
    scanf("d%",&s[i].Sales);
}

printf("This is the information entered:\n");      //displaying info
{
    printf("%s: ",s[i].name);

    printf("Sales %d:\n",s[i].Sales);
}

bubbleSort(s,n);                  //function call of bubblesort


printf("This is the information entered:\n");            //see new information after bubblesort
{
    printf("%s: ",s[i].name);

    printf("Sales %d:\n",s[i].Sales);
}

free( s );

return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(SalesRep *a,int n)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        if((*(a+j)).Sales>(*(a+j+1)).Sales)
        {
            temp=(*(a+j)).Sales;
            (*(a+j)).Sales=(*(a+j+1)).Sales;
            (*(a+j+1)).Sales=temp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error:

```
 (11)error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
 (11) error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
 (11)error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
 (11)error C2059: syntax error : ')'
 (28)error C2065: 'SalesRep' : undeclared identifier
 (28)error C2059: syntax error : ')'
 (46)warning C4013: 'bubbleSort' undefined; assuming extern returning int
 (61)error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
 (61)error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
 (61)error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
 (61)error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Comment: I don't know how anyone can tell you more than what the compiler is already telling you. Fix the syntax errors and make the compiler stop complaining.

Comment: What compiler are you using where it doesn't give you line numbers?

Comment: For one thing, whenever you refer to `SalesRep`, you need to specify it's a struct: For example, `s=(SalesRep*)calloc(n,sizeof(SalesRep));` should be `s=(struct SalesRep*)calloc(n,sizeof(structSalesRep));`. This happens several times in your code.

Comment: Those error messages no doubt came with line numbers. Or if you're using an IDE, clicking on the error would highlight the offending source line. Start hunting those syntax issues down one by one.

Comment: Aside: please decide whether to use `scanf` or `scanf_s` and be consistent. There are significant differences, best read the man page about extra arguments needed (not for `%d`).

Comment: Another aside, in the bubble sort, the loops are wrong. Perhaps `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)  { for(j = i + 1;  j < n; j++) . . .`

Comment: my bad i updated the code with the line numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the sole thing that you are missing when compiling this with a C compiler is the following:

```
typedef struct SalesRep SalesRep;
```

Unlike C++, in C, a tag introduced through `struct` like `SalesRep` in `struct SalesRep` is only identified as a type when referred to as `struct SalesRep` (and not through `SalesRep` allone). The `typedef` allows you to use `SalesRep` as type directly (without the `struct`-prefix.

All other issues will go away once you fix this, e.g. the error in prototype for `bubbleSort`, consequently the missing declaration when calling `bubbleSort`,...

Comment: thank you it fixed the problem, will use this as a future reference